# Filter an array of objects with nested arrays based on another array

Tags: javascript

I've 2 different APIs. first one returns an array of event objects (this data set is growing and expected to be large). each event has a category array that has a list of strings. The other API returns an array of filter objects. each filter has a "name" property and an array of keywords. any keyword included in the categories array in any event should go under this filter name.
The ultimate goal is to have a list of filters on the screen and when a user click on a filter I should render all events under this filter.

Event Object Example:

```
{
            "text": {
                "headline": "Headline example",
                "text": "event description "
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://www.google.com/",
                "caption": "",
                "credit": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "National",
                "Canada",
                "British Columbia"
            ]
        }
```

Filters Object Example:

```
{
    "filters": [
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Atlantic",
                "New Brunswick",
                "Newfoundland and Labrador",
                "Prince Edward Island",
                "Nova Scotia"
            ],
            "name": "Atlantic"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "ontario",
                "Quebec"
            ],
            "name": "Central Canada"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Manitoba",
                "Saskatchewan",
                "Alberta"
            ],
            "name": "Prairie Provinces"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "British Columbia"
            ],
            "name": "West Coast"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Nunavut",
                "Northwest Territories",
                "Yukon Territory"
            ],
            "name": "North"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "National"
            ],
            "name": "National"
        }
    ]
}
```

After a couple of days working on it I came up with this solution.

```
function filterTimelineData(filtersObj, timelineData) {
  if (!timelineData || !filtersObj) return [];
  // create a new object with filters "name" as key;
  const filters = Object.keys(filtersObj);
  const filteredTimelineData = Object.keys(filtersObj).reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: [] }), {});

  const filteredData = timelineData.events.reduce((acc, current) => {

    let filterMatch = false;
    let filterMatchName = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
      filterMatch = current.categories.some(item => {
        return filtersObj[filters[i]].includes(item.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });
      if (filterMatch && filterMatchName !== filters[i]) { // to avoid duplicated items with different categories under the same filter
        filterMatchName = filters[i];
        acc[filters[i]].push(current);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, filteredTimelineData);

  return filteredData;
}

export function timelineFiltersObj(filters) {
  const filtersObj = filters.filters.reduce((acc, current) => {
    const filterName = current.name.replace(/ /g, '_').toLocaleLowerCase();
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(filterName)) {
      acc[filterName] = [];
    }
    acc[filterName] = [].concat(current.keywords.map(item => item.toLocaleLowerCase()));
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return filtersObj;
}
```

Desired output:

1. An object or an array for all filters to be rendered on the screen
2. An object with filters name as a key and the value would be an array of events that has any keyword that matches any of this filter keywords

check this code example: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/BMork/1kL8sm0a/)

My Questions:

- Is there an easier/simpler way to solve this problem?
- I'm passing "filteredTimelineData" object as initial value to .reduce function. Is this legitimate? I couldn't find any answers online to this question specifically.
- from a time complexity prospective. will this code cause any memory issue if the dataset grows?

Comment: Your desired output is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry about that. The desired output is to have an object with filters name as keys and the value would be an array of events that match this filter.

Comment: Could you please add the desired output in the question, it would be more clear then.

Comment: Make a clear example of what the data looks like before and after filter. From your example, it's really not clear

Comment: added a link to a code example.
Sorry, should have added that at the beginning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way to get the above result. I am using `JavaScript ES5` features in this solution which is supported by almost all the browsers except IE9

```js
const filters = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Atlantic",
                "New Brunswick",
                "Newfoundland and Labrador",
                "Prince Edward Island",
                "Nova Scotia"
            ],
            "name": "Atlantic"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "ontario",
                "Quebec"
            ],
            "name": "Central Canada"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Manitoba",
                "Saskatchewan",
                "Alberta"
            ],
            "name": "Prairie Provinces"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "British Columbia"
            ],
            "name": "West Coast"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "Nunavut",
                "Northwest Territories",
                "Yukon Territory"
            ],
            "name": "North"
        },
        {
            "keywords": [
                "National"
            ],
            "name": "National"
        }
    ]
};
const timelineData = {
    "events": [
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "New Brunswick"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "National"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://youtu.be/poOO4GN3TN4"
            },
            "categories": [
                "Northwest Territories"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "Ontario"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "National"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://philanthropy.cdn.redcross.ca/timeline/July2020-3.jpg"
            },
            "categories": [
                "British Columbia"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "Alberta"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "Prince Edward Island"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "National"
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "headline": "headline example",
                "text": "event-descriprion"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                "National"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var categoriesToEventsMap = timelineData.events.reduce((res, event) => {
    event.categories.forEach(c=> {
        res = {
            ...res,
            [c.toLowerCase()]: [...(res[c.toLowerCase()] || []), event]
        }
    });
    return res;
}, {})

var result = filters.filters.reduce((acc, filter) => {
    
    let events = []
    const filterName = filter.name.replace(' ', '_').toLowerCase();
    filter.keywords.forEach((key)=>{
        events = [...events, ...(categoriesToEventsMap[key.toLowerCase()] || [])];
     });
    acc[filterName] = [...(acc[filterName] || []), ...events]
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've integrated your answer in my code base and tested it. It is definitely simpler, However, when tested with large dataset the execution time is longer than the original solution!